# Making vector fonts from metafont sources in LuaTeX?

Tags: fonts, luatex, metapost, luaotfload

According to the presentation "TUG 2020 — Marcel Krüger — MetaPost-based, dynamic extensible delimiters for LuaTeX" it is possible to generate "fully hinted, vector glyphs" from (changed?) metafont sources inside LuaTeX.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VzxPn1i6id8

I did not find any more information about this. I only see some code like `\font\Cmr [cmr10.mp] at 10pt` in the video.

Maybe someone can explain what to do exactly? How does a file `cmr10.mp` have to look like? What restriction are there?

I think this is really interesting because of the lack of optical sizes in all the OTF versions of Computer Modern.

Expamples:

Latin Modern Bold Italic (only 10pt optical size),
Latin Modern Math Math / New Computer Modern Math (only one optical size, no bold font)

I (and I think many others) would like to have every optical size of everything (icluding math and bold and bold math fonts) as it was possible in Metafont by changing parameters. Latin Modern and New Computer Modern are really disappointing.

Sorry, no MWE because I don't know what to do and cannot find further information.

Comment: To get hinted fonts you need MetaType1 sources (so for example the Latin Modern sources can be used to get hinted fonts), when directly using (almost) unchanged Computer Modern MetaFont you can only get unhinted Type 3 fonts (of course still vector fonts). The original version needed some engine patches but that should no longer be necessary, I'll see if I can adapt it easily for more modern LuaTeX versions and will try to write answer then.

Comment: OK, thank you. As far as I know the MetaType1 sources are not parametrized, so there would be no chance to get a "Latin Modern 17 Math Bold" or a "Latin Modern 5 Bold Italic". Or can hinting be added to Computer Modern Metafont sources?

Comment: Sorry if my questions sound naive but I don't know where to get the knowledge.

Comment: The issue is that hinting requires Type 1 (or TrueType) fonts and Computer Modern uses features which are not compatible with these formats. Therefore hinting Computer Modern directly isn't really an option. That's not too much of an issue since hinting isn't used much anymore anyway, but also general font rendering in many viewers is somewhat worse for Type 3 than for Type 1 fonts sadly. It strongly depends on the viewer though.

Comment: The other big issue with using Computer Modern is of course the very small number of supported characters.

Comment: I understand ... So only a font designer can add opticle sizes to Latin Modern/Latin Modern Math and New Computer Modern/New Computer Modern Math. The freedom from Metafont has gone.

Comment: There is mftrace and potrace to trace the outlines of rasterized Type 3 fonts. Of course this comes with a whole new bag of problems and the traced outlines will never exactly match the MetaFont outlines.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger: Did you think about the adaption to LuaTeX?